# Does a cosmological scale parameter in FLRW split the frame bundle?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry

Suppose we're looking at an FLRW cosmological metric. Then a set of orthonormal frames on our spacetime in the comoving frame looke like the set:

$$\theta=\left\{ a(x^{0})\theta^{i},\theta^{0}\right\} $$

Where $i=1,2,3$ runs over the spatial indices and $ a(x^{0}) $ is the cosmological scale factor. Considering the usual metric-compatible connection on our spacetime the ensuing derivatives of the scale factor would seem to split the frame bundle (in the comoving frame). Without calculating explicitly I'm expecting something like:

$$SO(3,1)\rightarrow SO(3)\times\mathbb{R}$$

How would I go about determining the precise reduction of the frame bundle for a cosmological scale factor?

From a slightly different point of view, a Riemannian 4-manifold only admits a Lorentzian metric if the structure group of it's frame bundle reduces similar to the form above (i.e. if there's a line bundle over the 4-manifold). Of course this is different from the above splitting...or is it?